# Is my Joda Time format pattern incorrect to produce a `T` and `Z` inside the parsed DateTime output?

Tags: java, jodatime, date-format

Using [Joda Time's pattern syntax](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) below, this input string:

```
Sunday, January 09, 2011 6:15:00 PM
```

becomes this datetime:

```
2011-01-09T06:15:00.000Z
```

Code:

```
String start = "Sunday, January 09, 2011 6:15:00 PM";

DateTimeFormatter parser1 = 
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss aa");

DateTime startTime = parser1.parseDateTime(start);
```

Is this format pattern incorrect? If not, what are the `T` and `Z` doing inside the DateTime output?

```
2011-01-09T06:15:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've only shown the *parsing* code - not how you've converted the `DateTime` value back to a `String`.

I strongly suspect you're just calling `toString()`, which use the default `DateTime` ISO8601 format.

Don't forget that a `DateTime` value represents an instant in time in a particular time zone and calendar system - it has no concept of format patterns. The "T" and "Z" aren't in the `DateTime` value - they're just in the default *representation* of the value. It's like when you convert an `int` to a string - it happens to use decimal, but the number itself is just a number.

If you want to format a `DateTime` in a specific way, you should use

```
String text = formatter.print(startTime);
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon. Yes, I was calling `toString` as you guessed.

Answer (score 14):

T: Denotes start of "time part" of the string.
Zone: 'Z' outputs offset. I suppose in thise case is GMT.
Source:http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

I always use this format string: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

And, yes, they are not incorrect, if they are present in your string.

Comment: Thanks cheekoo, I was missing the single quotes in the 'T'!

Comment: Z stands for Zulu Time, which corresponds to UTC, not GMT

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating your own formatter, you can use one predefined by Joda time.
You will find them in `org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat`.

In fact, in your case I would use `ISODateTimeFormat.basicDateTimeNoMillis` formatter. I think it has the pattern you were looking for: `yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ`